# how to refere to image as URLs in outlook mails

Tags: sharepoint-online, picture-library

I would like to add pictures in outlook HTML mails (inline, not attached).

These images are in a library in Sharepoint Online and are accessible to everyone in the company.
I would like to use the http link to that image in a mail in outlook.
Right now it seems that if I opened the image in SPO; it will be fetched from the browser cache and be visible. If I haven't opened the image in SPO, it will show as a broken link.

So I would need some kind of direct link, that checks if the user is logged in or not.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Outlook attempts to the load the image via the URL, it's likely being met with a 403 HTTP error and therefore not displaying.

It's not guaranteed that the user has authenticated with SharePoint Online at the time of them opening the email. Most images in emails are loaded via URLs which are publicly accessible.

Comment: Indeed, you are probably right. I was hoping for some setup wherein the auth is not necessary.

Comment: Sadly, SharePoint Online no longer supports anonymous access sites (public facing websites) where you would store such a file. There is a way to share a file to anyone with the link but those links tend to expire.

Comment: If the answer helped, please upvote or mark it as the accepted answer to help inform the community.